# Showing a function of three variables is differentiable at a point

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am having trouble showing that the following function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  given by $$f(x,y,z) = xy + yz + xz$$ is differentiable at $(1,1,1)$. I have used the definition of differentiability along with the Jacobian to reduce the problem to showing that the limit $$\lim_{\textbf{x}\to (1,1,1)} \frac{|xz + xy + yz + 3 - 2(x+y+z)|}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 + (z-1)^2}} = 0$$ I have tried using the pinching principle, but could not find a useful upper bound. I also tried to use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits, but could not get anything useful. How does one show that this limit is equal to $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest to use the version that 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{(h,k,l)\rightarrow(0,0,0)}\dfrac{f(h,k,l)-f(1,1,1)-(2h+2k+2l)}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}+l^{2}}}.
\end{align*}
After simplifying, we get the inner expression as
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{hk+kl+lh}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}+l^{2}}},
\end{align*}
we now use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that 
\begin{align*}
|hk+kl+lh|\leq\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}+l^{2}}\sqrt{k^{2}+l^{2}+h^{2}}
\end{align*}
to get
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{hk+kl+lh}{\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}+l^{2}}}\right|\leq\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}+l^{2}}<\epsilon
\end{align*}
by choosing $\delta=\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you. This works, but how did you know to use the Cauchy Schwartz inequality? I also do not know how you recognised to do the h,k,l substitution.

Comment: Actually I tried differently, and I realize that with $h=x-1$, $k=y-1$, $l=z-1$, then our expressions mean the same thing. Back to your expression, because you want to eliminate the denominator about $x-1$, $y-1$, and $z-1$, so you need to rearrange the numerator to having some form that has to do with $x-1$, $y-1$, and $z-1$, so just go with $h,k,l$ substitution.

Comment: Actually if it were having only two variable, one uses Arithmetic-Geometric inequality, but not it has three variable, so go with Cauchy-Schwarz, and you know AG is a special case of CS.